# material-table edit/delete button change action

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using material-table in react js
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table

I need to redirect the user to a separate edit page for the item.

I don't understand how to redirect to the edit page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the "actions" property as described in their documentation: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions

```
<MaterialTable
        ...
        actions={[
          {
            icon: 'edit',
            tooltip: 'Edit User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You are editing ' + rowData.name)
          },
          {
            icon: 'delete',
            tooltip: 'Delete User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => confirm('You want to delete ' + rowData.name)
          }
        ]}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<TableCell>` as mentioned in the documentation and can create custom onClick method to open the action in new page.

https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting

Comment: Actually, I'm using the material-table package because it has search options. can I have the same search feature in the <TableCell>